# CASE and IN in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with my SQL Server request:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE M.StatutMandatId = 

CASE
    WHEN @Mandat = '1' THEN '5'
    WHEN @Mandat = '0' THEN 'IN(1,2,3,4,5)'
END
```

But I have this issue:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'IN(1,2,3)' to
>   data type int.

It's not possible to use IN like that?

Comment: Data type for StatutMandatId column?

Comment: I dont think you can do something like this because IN has some meaning and when you replace it in a string will cause a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do an `IN` like that, instead if you have to use the `CASE` do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
CASE
    WHEN @Mandat = '1' AND M.StatutMandatId = 5 THEN 1
    WHEN @Mandat = '0' AND M.StatutMandatId IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

It probably won't be very performant, I would instead restructure it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE
    (@Mandat = '1' AND M.StatutMandatId = 5)
 OR (@Mandat = '0' AND M.StatutMandatId IN(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't create dynamic SQL like that. You could achieve the same using the follow statement though

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE (M.StatutMandatId IN(1,2,3,4,5) AND @Mandat=0)
OR (M.StatutMandatId =5 AND @Mandat=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use caseand IN inside where following would work (need to use temporary table).

```
DECLARE @StatutMandatIds table (meetingstatus int)

insert into @StatutMandatIds select 1
insert into @StatutMandatIds select 2
insert into @StatutMandatIds select 3
insert into @StatutMandatIds select 4
insert into @StatutMandatIds select 5

SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE M.StatutMandatId IN 
(CASE
    WHEN @Mandat = '1' THEN 5
    WHEN @Mandat = '0' THEN (select * from @StatutMandatIds)
END)
```

OR you can do simplify like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE (@Mandat= '1' AND M.StatutMandatId = 5) OR (@Mandat = '0' AND M.StatutMandatId IN (1,2,3,4,5))
```